# ServiceStack Development Tooling?

Tags: servicestack

Not sure if this is the most effective place to ask this question. Please redirect if you think it is best posted elsewhere to reach a better audience.

I am currently building some tooling in Visual Studio 2013 (using NuPattern) for a project that implements standard REST service using the ServiceStack framework. That is, the tooling helps you implement REST services, that meet a set of design rules and guidelines (in this case advocated by the ApiGee guidelines) for good REST service design.

Based on some simple configuration by the service developer, for each resource they wish to expose as a REST endpoint, with any number of named verbs (of type: GET, PUT, POST or DELETE) the tooling generates the following code files, with conventional names and folder structure into the projects of your own solution in Visual Studio (all in C# at this point):

- The service class, and the service interface containing each named verb.
- Both the request DTO and response DTOs, containing each named field.
- The validator classes for each request DTO, which validates each request DTO field.
- a manager class (and interface) that handles the actual calls with data unwrapped from DTOs.
- Integration Tests that verify each verb with common edge test cases, and verifies status codes, web exceptions, basic connectivity.
- Unit Tests for each service and manager class, that verify parameters and common edge cases, and exception handling.
- etc.

The toolkit is proving to be extremely useful in getting directly to the inner coding of the actual service, by taking care of the SS plumbing in a consistent manner. From there is basically up to you what you do with the data passed to you from the request DTOs. 
Basically, once the service developer names the resource, and chooses the REST verbs they want to support (typically any of these common ones: Get, List, Create, Update, Delete), they simply jump straight to the implementation of the actual code which does the good stuff rather than worrying about coding up all the types around the web operations and plumbing them into the SS framework. Of course we support nested routes and that good stuff so that your REST API can evolve appropriately.

The toolkit is evolving as more is learned about building REST services with ServiceStack, and as we want to add more flexibility to it.

Since there is so much value being discovered with this toolkit in our specific project, I wanted to see if others in the ServiceStack community (particularly those new to it or old hands at it) would see any value in us making it open source, and let the community evolve it with their own expertise to help others move forward quicker with ServiceStack? 
(And, of course, selfishly give us a chance to pay forward to others, out of respect for the many contributions others have selflessly made in the ServiceStack communities that have helped us move forward.)

Let us know what you think, we can post a video demonstrating the toolkit as it is now so you can see what the developers experience is currently.

#### Video walkthrough of the VS.NET Extension

A video walking through of the workflow is available on:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejTyvKba_vo

#### Toolkit Project

The toolkit is now available here: 
https://github.com/jezzsantos/servicestacktoolkit

Comment: Hey Jezz, the best place to ask for feedback from the ServiceStack community is on the [ServiceStack G+ Group](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/112445368900682590445).

Comment: Video is now here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejTyvKba_vo